# Apply CSS class on element if current page in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am currently looking to add a CSS class if a page is active. What is the best way to do this in Phoenix currently? Is there a helper for this case?

```
def active(option, conn) do
  if option == conn.request_path do
    " class=\"active\""
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

In the template:

```
<%= "contact" |> active(@conn) |> raw %>
```

Answer (score 23):

We'll use `conn.path_info` which returns the current path as a list of strings instead of `conn.request_path`. We could use that to get in our `active_class` helper.

```
def active_class(conn, path) do
  current_path = Path.join(["/" | conn.path_info])
  if path == current_path do
    "active"
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Then we use it like:

```
<%= link "Users", to: user_path(@conn, :index), class: active_class(@conn, user_path(@conn, :index))%>
```

Note that we `user_path/2` twice above. We could DRY that up with another helper:

```
def active_link(conn, text, opts) do
  class = [opts[:class], active_class(conn, opts[:to])]
          |> Enum.filter(& &1) 
          |> Enum.join(" ")
  opts = opts
         |> Keyword.put(:class, class)
  link(text, opts)
end
```

Why use `conn.path_info` instead of `conn.request_path`? This is because `conn.request_path` will return the exact path the user requested. If user visits path `/foo/`, then `conn.request_path` will return `/foo/`. The problem with that is the router helper we will compare to will always return a path `/foo` without the trailing `/`.

Hope that helps! Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: This seems pretty clear and pretty simple, and works with paths directly. `conn.request_path` is in 0.15 master on github right now, but its not in < 0.15.

Comment: @rockerBOO you're right. It is in plug master. Tried it out but I'd still suggest using `conn.path_info`. I'll update my answer with why

Answer (score 6):

I have created a helper for this that looks like:

```
defmodule LinkHelper
  @doc """
  Calls `active_link/3` with a class of "active"
  """
  def active_link(conn, controllers) do
    active_link(conn, controllers, "active")
  end

  @doc """
  Returns the string in the 3rd argument if the expected controller
  matches the Phoenix controller that is extracted from conn. If no 3rd
  argument is passed in then it defaults to "active".

  The 2nd argument can also be an array of controllers that should
  return the active class.
  """
  def active_link(conn, controllers, class) when is_list(controllers) do
    if Enum.member?(controllers, Phoenix.Controller.controller_module(conn)) do
      class
    else
      ""
    end
  end

  def active_link(conn, controller, class) do
    active_link(conn, [controller], class)
  end
end
```

I then import this in the `def view` function inside of `web/web.ex`

```
def view do
  ...
  import LinkHelper
  ...
end
```

Usage:

```
<li class="<%= active_link(@conn, PageController)%>"><a href="<%= page_path(@conn, :index) %>">Home</a></li>
<li class="<%= active_link(@conn, [FooController, BarController])%>"><a href="<%= foo_path(@conn, :index) %>">Foo or Bar</a></li>
```

Comment: This seems like a good choice for integration into the Controller system. Some issues with your example code. `defmodule LinkHelper do` and  `import LinkHelper`

Comment: @rockerBOO good spot - must have forgotten to update the import when I copied it across!

Comment: Doesn't this approach set a link to "active" for all the actions of the controller you pass to it? For example, `page_path(@conn, :index)` and `page_path(@conn, :show)` will both be set to active if you pass `PageController` to `active_link/3`. Don't we want show page to be "active" only if we're in page.show?

Answer (score 1):

The following code is working with me, including parameters tracking:

helper function goes as following:

```
def active_class(path, conn) do
  query_string = cond do
    conn.query_string == "" -> ""
    true -> "?#{conn.query_string}"
  end
  if ("#{conn.request_path}#{query_string}" === path) do "active" else "" end
end
```

and in the view :

```
<% important_issues_path = issue_path(@conn, :index, important: true) %>

<%= link "important", to: important_issues_path,
    class: "nav-link #{
      MyApp.TheHelper.active_class(important_issues_path, @conn)
   }"
%>
```